# A way to 'save' modern pages or print them to PDF

Tags: pdf, aspx, printing

Object: Communication site with standard modern pages with combinations of text and images.

I would like to find a way to 'save' the content or print it.

I have tried to print and the result is not optimal at times since the web page does not adapt to A4 sheets. I have tried to Print to XPS and print to PDF and it is the same. I am talking about around 50 pages of articles that I would like to 'save'.

Is there a way other than taking screenshots of every portion?

Answer (score 0):

The best-practice way to optimise a web page for print formats is to specify style rules for that medium in the global stylesheets of an application.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries

The gist being, somewhere in the stylesheet you should have a section like the following:

```
@media print {
    header nav, footer {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

which would be used when you used a browser's Print function to send a document to a physical printer or PDF renderer. Assuming the correct use of those elements, it would render the article without the site's navigation items nor the footer.

- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: He would have to embed that CSS snippet into either an Application Extension or inject it before the <body></body> element.  The most reliable way would be to use an application extension using SPfx